# highlight only works when in the first tab/window

Tags: vim

I have the following line in my `.vimrc` file:

```
" Highlight macros
highligh Macro cterm=bold
match Macro /\v(\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*(\_[^*]|\*\_[^/])*)@<!<[A-Z_]{2,}>/
```

Basically it highlights capitalised text not in a c++ comment (ie. macros in the codebase I'm working on). That's fine, but it only works sometimes. If I open a file using `vim myfile.cpp` then it shows up, but when I open a new tab using `:tabe otherfile.cpp` the highlighting does not appear in the new file (but remains in the old tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to associate the Macro match with cpp files using an autocommand.

```
highlight Macro cterm=bold
au BufNewFile, BufRead {*.cpp,*.hpp,*.ipp} match Macro /\v(\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*(\_[^*]|\*\_[^/])*)@<!<[A-Z_]{2,}>/
```

This way each time you open or create a .cpp, .hpp or .ipp file the match will be in effect.

You could also change that pattern to just `*.?pp`, unless you expect to be using other .xpp variants for which matching is not desired.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) Would you be able to show how I would modify this to do it for all `.cpp`, `.hpp` and `.ipp` files?

Comment: You should be able to add the other type of files right in there: au BufNewFile, BufRead \*.cpp,\*.hpp,*.ipp ...

Comment: @Jay I've added that to my `.vimrc` but it doesn't seem to have any effect (no highlighting with or without new windows). Does it work on your setup?

Comment: @Jason Yes, this approach is working for me. I am using it with a very simple pattern to validate. Are you using Vim or GVim?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution instead of BufNewFile,BufRead

```
highligh Macro cterm=bold
au filetype cpp match Macro /\v(\/\/[^\n]*|\/\*(\_[^*]|\*\_[^/])*)@<!<[A-Z_]{2,}>/
```

This will fire anytime the buffers filetype option is set to cpp.

In my vim installation, it's matching the following as cpp filetype

```
" C++
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cxx,*.c++,*.hh,*.hxx,*.hpp,*.ipp,*.moc,*.tcc,*.inl setf cpp
if has("fname_case")
  au BufNewFile,BufRead *.C,*.H setf cpp
endif
```

Comment: Hmm, it works for the first window but not for any others, just like with the original code. If you open a file and then run `:vsp otherfile.hpp` does it work for you?